# Direct traffic Google Analytics bots?

Tags: google-analytics, bots

Our website is based in Sydney, Australia. We're getting more than 2,000 unique visitors from Paris every month - which is about 40% of our site traffic. The traffic arrives directly to our homepage and spend less than a few seconds on it.

There is no reason for anyone from Paris to visit the site.

Is it possible these are bots? I ask as it seems a massive amount of UV's for just bot activity? Seems odd, so wonder if anyone has seen this before?

Thanks for your time,

G

Answer (score 0):

Very possible. You could look into several things. See if:

1. traffic is from a single service provider
2. browser is of a single type (from my experience, bots favour IE)
3. visits are from desktop only
4. bounce rate is high
5. time spent per visit is low
6. there are no interactions with the page

If you see all these patterns, then likely you have bots, and you will have to develop a strategy to filter them out of your useful data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a traffic bot which can't be detected by-
   -bounce rate
   -service provider
   -location
   -browser or system/device(os) type
   -time spent
   -interaction with page..

but there are many other things which are used to detect traffic bot i.e. screen resolution, organic traffic..most of the traffic bots directly visits website pages and (not provided) section of analytics gets higher numbers then keywords..Its the best way to detect traffic as coming from bots.